# Switching parts of a filename

Tags: windows-7, pdf, rename, filenames, batch-rename

I have a large batch of pdf files which are all in the format "[something] somethingelse".

How can I switch the first part and the end part around to achieve "somethingelse [something]"?

For example (before and after):

```
[P. Morandi] Field and Galois Theory
Field and Galois Theory [P. Morandi]

[D. S. Bridges] Foundations of Real and Abstract Analysis
Foundations of Real and Abstract Analysis [D. S. Bridges] 

[J. G. Ratcliffe] Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds
Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds [J. G. Ratcliffe]

[R. E. Edwards] Fourier Series - A Modern Introduction Volume 1
Fourier Series - A Modern Introduction Volume 1 [R. E. Edwards]

[B. Bollobás] Graph Theory - An Introductory Course
Graph Theory - An Introductory Course [B. Bollobás]
```

Comment: Please add a tag for your operating system.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm far from being a programmer at all so I'm unable to provide any attempts apart from manually cutting and pasting the filenames the way that I want them. A task like this seems like it should be simple enough to automate, but I'm unable to come up with any such code myself.

Comment: Please add a few before and after example names and I will see what I can do for you.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for your efforts - hopefully my edit provides enough examples (I can provide more if required).

Comment: No file extensions? I will look at this later this evening. It's supper time for me :)

Comment: @DavidPostill Edited to say that they're all pdf files. Enjoy your supper :)

Comment: Supper enjoyed and answer written :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I switch the first part and the end part around?

> For example (before and after):
>
> ```
> [P. Morandi] Field and Galois Theory.pdf
> Field and Galois Theory [P. Morandi].pdf
> ```

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq delims=] tokens=1,2" %%a in (`dir /b *.pdf`) do (
  rem %%b is end part of name and will become 1st part
  rem remove extension
  set _first=%%~nb
  rem remove leading space
  set _first=!_first:~1!
  ren "%%a]%%b" "!_first! %%a].pdf"
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- Tested with the first two example filenames in your question.

Example usage:

```
> dir *.pdf
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test

02/10/2016  19:43                 0 [D. S. Bridges] Foundations of Real and Abstract Analysis.pdf
02/10/2016  19:42                 0 [P. Morandi] Field and Galois Theory.pdf
               2 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  1,733,769,015,296 bytes free

> test

> dir *.pdf
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test

02/10/2016  19:42                 0 Field and Galois Theory [P. Morandi].pdf
02/10/2016  19:43                 0 Foundations of Real and Abstract Analysis [D. S. Bridges].pdf
               2 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  1,733,769,015,296 bytes free
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.
- [ren](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) - Rename a file or files.
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! It works perfectly (with the exception of authors with non-English characters such as š, but these are rare and can be done manually). The further reading section is a huge bonus to this answer <insert some saying about teaching a man to fish>.

Comment: @IrregularUser You might be able to fix the odd characters by using the correct code page (I don't have much experience of this). See [chcp](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) - Change the active console Code Page. The default code page is determined by the Windows Locale.